# Apache Camel: How to use a Property placeholder to enable or disable a route?

Tags: routes, apache-camel, property-placeholder

I am new to Apache Camel, and have a problem statement in hand. I want to build a code where I can refer to the flags in the camel properties and allow a route to be enabled/disabled based on the flags availability in the properties file.
How do I proceed with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.autoStartup("{{propertyName}}")` function from the Java DSL. For example:

```
from("activemq:queue:special").autoStartup("{{startupRouteProperty}}").to("file://backup");
```

[http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html#Configuringroutestartuporderingandautostartup-Configuringwhetherarouteshouldbestartedornot,usingabooleanorString,inJavaDSL)

Comment: Actually, I want to achieve something like this   from("some data source"). choice(). when(properties contain flag x)- do some action. otherwise()-skip  the referred route and proceed. Can this be achieved. If yes, can you please guide me with the syntax?